# How to read a list of paragraphs in MS Word docx file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ms-word

How to read a list of paragraphs and their styles from MS Word docx file using javascript without interactive session (service side)?

Comment: Are you talking about JS running in the client browser to read a local file without interacting with a web server, or talking about server-side JS code running without a request from a browser?

Comment: server-side JS which needs to process docx file, parse all paragraphs, their styles and return some statistic in response